# Ecommerce item limits

Tags: javascript, html, css, e-commerce

I have a question about using e-commerce with self publishing.

I am physically disabled and, as such, I am limited by US federal law on what I can earn. However, I would like to try my hand at self publishing. The problem is I am not sure how to restrict my income in case my book is successful. I am not trying to replace a job, but I would like a part time income doing what I like, which is writing.

I have talked with Amazon and Smashwords about if they can impose monthly limits on payouts. They will not. On top of this, they pay quarterly, which is a nightmare for my trying to establish a predictable income from self publishing that is below my legally mandated monthly cap.

My only alternative would be to implement an e-commerce solution on my own site. I have some HTML5/CSS/JS/PHP/MYSQL experience, but not to this level. Is there a way I can implement a limited number of purchases on my site via a virtual inventory, and then restrict further purchases until the next month?

Thanks.

Comment: i would imagine using any e-commerce software would provide you this ability.  Just set the available quantity to be lower or equal to `qty * saleprice <= max revenue allowed` and you are good to go.  If you want to take backorders and fill them the next month when your limit frees up again, that feature should exist on just about every existing cart out there.

Comment: I think all the leading e-commerce packages allow that type of setup. Try  https://www.prestashop.com/ or http://magento.com/

Comment: Thank you. Would you have any advice about good e-commerce solutions to begin with?

I prefer hand coding my pages from scratch using Dreamweaver instead of relying on something like Wordpress because free Wordpress restricts my ability to make money from ads, to my knowledge, without running my own Wordpress server.

Comment: Thank you, Kurt. Your comment was added right before I posted.

I hope there's something that I can just drag and drop into the HTML/CSS, add a little JS for remaining monthly purchases, and go.

I assume there's also a small surcharge for various commerce solutions handling CC validation.